# How to fix this "Attempted import error: 'ComponentProps' is not exported from './component'." after upgrade typescript version to 3.7.3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs

This is my issue/upgrade scenario:

- upgrade **typescript** from **3.5.2** to **3.7.3**
- react component library build with typescript and dashboard built with CreateReactApplication and in javascript
- main update of code after upgrading the typescript library was to replace this import export of ComponentProps types ...

```
import { ComponentProps } from './component/component'
export type ComponentProps = ComponentProps
```

- ... with this way

```
export { ComponentProps } from './component/component'
```

and this is the issue that happens when I try to build the dashboard:

```
../PROJECT/components.ts

Attempted import error: 'ComponentProps' is not exported from './component/component'.
 @ ./DASHBOARD/views/components/component/component.jsx
 @ ./DASHBOARD/routes/views.js
 @ ./DASHBOARD/routes/routes-views.js
 @ ./DASHBOARD/routes/index.js
 @ ./DASHBOARD/app.jsx
 @ ./DASHBOARD/index.jsx
 @ multi @babel/polyfill ./config/dom-polyfill.js ./src/app/index.jsx
```

It seems there is something with babel in the component project after the typescript upgrade, but I'm not really sure what to look for.
Ideas? Thanks

Comment: This way worked `export * from './component/component'`, but another error was lying in the code - still typescript related but not related to the question. After all it got fixed.